# How do I switch to a higher resolution in Centos 6 installed on a virtual machine (VirtualBox)?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, display, resolution, centos

I have installed Centos 6 on a virtual machine (virtualbox). Maximum available screen resolution is 800x600. How do I get higher resolutions?

Comment: This might be a bug in CentOS 6. Look at the release-notes for RedHat 6.1 regarding problems with 800 x 600.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the VirtualBox Guest Additions in the virtual machine. You can do this by selecting "Install Guest Additions" from the Devices menu. This will install a device driver into the guest OS that will dynamically adjust the screen resolution as you resize the VirtualBox window.

Comment: Thanks. I had edited xorg.conf file under /etc/X11 to get custom resolutions. I had added 1920x1080. When I rebooted, it couldn't start X window. Then I entered rescue mode and deleted xorg.conf file. Because I read that it creates a default xorg.conf file if it is deleted. I rebooted again, X window started, but there were no xorg.conf file under /etc/X11. Why wasn't it created? And, isn't this file necessary for X window to start? Why didn't the absence of xorg.conf result in any errors?

Comment: One of the recent versions of xorg eliminated the need for xorg.conf. You only need xorg.conf now if the default settings guessed by xorg are not to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

You need Virtual Box guest extensions.

In order to install them you first need the RPMForge repository added for yum, follow these instructions:

> http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-f0c3ecee3dbb407e4eed79a56ec0ae92d1398e01

Then run this command in a terminal:

```
yum install dkms
```

Comment: thank you so much @Beachhouse Sir.. work like charm for me.. i am using `CentOS 6.5`

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox Guest Additions includes the screen drivers for auto-resizing.

I find I occasionally need to rerun the GuestAdditions after installing software, and frequently so after doing a system update.  Following re-install of GuestAdditions, auto-resizing still unavailable until I do a system restart on the guest.  Then auto-resize is available again.